# Asynchronous triggers in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I need to know what is the meaning of "asynchronous trigger" and is there difference between asynchronous triggers and the normal triggers that is used in SQL Server after or before inserting, updating, deleting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're getting confused with Service Brokers.

Triggers always execute **synchronously**, in the context of a given transaction. If you need to invoke an asynchronous process from **within** a trigger, use a [Service Broker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345108%28SQL.90%29.aspx).

It's basically like a Queue - you **send** things to the queue, then can go on about your business without waiting for it to finish.

However, there is a lot more to it than that, have a read of the link.